# PHP Regex to extract <a> from html

Tags: php, regex, python-2.7, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract  tags from HTML that match a specific pattern.  Currently I use:

```
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?[^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {...}
```

Which correctly gets all the  elements however I want the group 3 (.*) (the text of the link) to contain the text "Find Tickets" but all my attempts to incorporate the text have not worked.  Also, the link elements inner html can contain more than "Find Tickets" - that is to say it should match on something like `.*Find Tickets.*`

Can anybody help me out here please I've been getting nowhere with this.

Update:
An example of the specific element I'm trying to grab:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fthelittleboxoffice.com%2Fheritagehotel%2Fevent%2Fview%2F22847&amp;h=RAQFYdp-K&amp;s=1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;https:\\/\\/thelittleboxoffice.com\\/heritagehotel\\/event\\/view\\/22847&quot;);" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/l.php?u=https\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fthelittleboxoffice.com\\u00252Fheritagehotel\\u00252Fevent\\u00252Fview\\u00252F22847&amp;h=RAQFYdp-K&amp;s=1&quot;);"><div id="u_0_p">Find Tickets</div></a><
```

Thanks
Josh

Comment: Are you just wanting the link text or the `href` value, **both** or the entire `a` tags ??

Comment: Can you please update your post to show what the string is that you're trying to match against and what you're hoping to achieve with the match?

Comment: I'm primarily after the href - the link text itself is optional (ie.  I'm not going to use it for anything).

Answer (score 1):

Use the right [**tool**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for the job, not a regular expression.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML data

$links = $xpath->query('//a[contains(., "Find Tickets")]');

foreach ($links as $link) {
   $results[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
}

print_r($results);
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/371527)

Comment: Thanks, but I actually started with hat approach but it doesn't work because the element I'm after s actually embedded in a html comment so regex is a better tool for this job.

Comment: I don't see how regex is a better approach for this, there are ways you can manipulate XPath to achieve this.

Comment: none the less - I've chosen to use regex and the question is about regex not other approaches.  If you can write an xpath to find a comment containing a <a href=...> thats text contains Find Tickets - bring it on then :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having a little trouble understanding what it is exactly that you are after.  Here's my best stab at it, though.

```
<?php

$string = '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fthelittleboxoffice.com%2Fheritagehotel%2Fevent%2Fview%2F22847&amp;h=RAQFYdp-K&amp;s=1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;https:\\/\\/thelittleboxoffice.com\\/heritagehotel\\/event\\/view\\/22847&quot;);" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/l.php?u=https\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fthelittleboxoffice.com\\u00252Fheritagehotel\\u00252Fevent\\u00252Fview\\u00252F22847&amp;h=RAQFYdp-K&amp;s=1&quot;);"><div id="u_0_p">Find Tickets</div></a><';



if (preg_match('~(<a href(.*?)Find Tickets(.*?)</a>)~i', $string, $matches)) {
    print "<PRE><FONT COLOR=ORANGE>"; print_r($matches); print "</FONT></PRE>";
}
```

All I'm really doing here is looking for a string starting with `<a href` followed by something until it hits `Find Tickets` and possibly more stuff until it hits the closing `</a>`.

This is a really general regex, but it's something you can build off of if you're looking for something more specific.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so from your comment, I think I have a better picture of what you are looking for.  Here is an updated REGEX that will pull out the URL of the link where the text of the link matches `Find Tickets`.

```
<?php

$string = '
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="color: blue;">Google</a>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fthelittleboxoffice.com%2Fheritagehotel%2Fevent%2Fview%2F22847&amp;h=RAQFYdp-K&amp;s=1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;https:\\/\\/thelittleboxoffice.com\\/heritagehotel\\/event\\/view\\/22847&quot;);" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/l.php?u=https\\u00253A\\u00252F\\u00252Fthelittleboxoffice.com\\u00252Fheritagehotel\\u00252Fevent\\u00252Fview\\u00252F22847&amp;h=RAQFYdp-K&amp;s=1&quot;);"><div id="u_0_p">Find Tickets</div></a>

<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>';

if (preg_match('~<a href="(.*?)"(?:.*?)(?:(?=Find Tickets))(?:.*?)</a>~i', $string, $matches)) {
    print "<PRE><FONT COLOR=ORANGE>"; print_r($matches); print "</FONT></PRE>";
}
```

So here's what this expression does:

- `(.*?)` - This is the part that actually captures the URL and stores it into `$matches[1]`.
- `(?:.*?)` - This allows anything to be after the URL up until it hits the next part (a lookahead).  Since we don't actually need this info, the `?:` tells REGEX not to remember what it finds.
- `(?:(?=Find Tickets))` - This is a positive lookahed meaning that in order to make a match, the text `Find Tickets` *has* to come next.  As in the previous item, we use `?:` to tell it that it doesn't actually need to remember the match.  You can probably include html brackets around the text to further lock it down if it's matching things like "Do Not Find Tickets" - `(?=>Find Tickets<)`.
- `(?:.*?)` - This final part is the same as earlier and just matches anything up until the closing `</a>` tag.

From the `$string` above, that will give you this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fthelittleboxoffice.com%2Fheritagehotel%2Fevent%2Fview%2F22847&amp;h=RAQFYdp-K&amp;s=1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onmouseover="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;https:\/\/thelittleboxoffice.com\/heritagehotel\/event\/view\/22847&quot;);" onclick="LinkshimAsyncLink.swap(this, &quot;https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/l.php?u=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fthelittleboxoffice.com\u00252Fheritagehotel\u00252Fevent\u00252Fview\u00252F22847&amp;h=RAQFYdp-K&amp;s=1&quot;);"><div id="u_0_p">Find Tickets</div></a>
    [1] => https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fthelittleboxoffice.com%2Fheritagehotel%2Fevent%2Fview%2F22847&amp;h=RAQFYdp-K&amp;s=1
)
```

And `$matches[1]` contains the URL.

Hopefully that hits the target for you!

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it seems to match more than once for the document.  There will be only one occurrence of Find Tickets but I do need the href value in a group where as this one would include text after the closing " as part of the group.  My original regex is really good at pulling out <a href> elements but I need it to only pull out elements also containing "Find Tickets" in the link text.

Comment: I think I now understand what it is you are looking for.  I updated my post to  reflect that.  Hopefully it is what you were wanting.